# OS X: Launch daemon doesn't start until user logs in

Tags: macos, daemon

I have a daemon that normally loads with the operating system - except on one MacBook Pro. The daemon doesn't seem to load until the first user logs in - and then it keeps running despite log offs and log ins. The MacBook Pro boots up quite fast and when the first user logs in, there's a progress bar (in stead of the spinning wheel) and the log in seems to take a while.

I suspect that this computer is configured to some kind of fast boot mode but I haven't been able find out whether this can be switched off or somehow configured?

Secondly, I need the daemon to run before anyone logs in - is there a way to make sure that the daemon is loaded despite this fast boot mode (that I suspect) .

The MacBook Pro runs the latest El Capitan.

Comment: This is OT for StackOverflow, so it might get closed. Where's the .plist located? The progress bar is probably because the user is using FileVault (disk encryption).

Comment: The .plist is in /Library/LaunchDaemons.
Yes, FileVault is enabled.
I don't understand why this shouldn't be for Stack Overflow (assuming "OT" = "NOT") - it would seem very relevant to Daemon development why a Daemon aren't loaded in some cases.

Comment: OT = Off Topic. I think [_Super User_](http://superuser.com/) might be more suited. I think that FileVault is the reason for the daemon not starting: until the user has entered their credentials, the disk is encrypted, so the OS doesn't have access to the configuration files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That computer's system volume is encrypted with [FileVault 2](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204837), which means that the operating system itself cannot start until one of the users supplies their password (which is needed to derive the volume encryption key). Until the first user logs in, there is no OS running at all (the progress bar is an indicator of the OS booting), so it's not possible for your daemon to run before then.

If you need your daemon to run immediately after the computer is powered on, you must turn off FileVault on that computer. If that computer needs to be encrypted for security reasons, then you're not going to be able to have your daemon load immediately.