# How to run system service before login in macOS 12.5.1?

Tags: macos, apple-m1, daemon, launchd

I put the plist file in /Library/LaunchDaemons directory, chown to root and run `sudo launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.nginx.plist` to enable and load it.

```bash
zyl@imac:~% ls -l  /Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.nginx.plist
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  906  6  4 21:20 /Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.nginx.plist
```

Then I reboot, waiting at login screen for some minutes. Before I login with a user/password, the service does not run.

After I login and check the create time of `/Users/xxxxx/stderr.log`, it shows the file was created after login.

The Os is macOs 12.5.1 running at apple-m1.
I don't know how to make my service running without login.
Anyone knows please help.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd"> 
<plist version="1.0"> 
<dict> 
     <key>Label</key> 
     <string>homebrew.mxcl.nginx</string> 
<!-- 
     <key>LimitLoadToSessionType</key> 
     <array> 
         <string>Aqua</string> 
         <string>Background</string> 
         <string>LoginWindow</string> 
         <string>StandardIO</string> 
         <string>System</string> 
     </array> 
--> 
     <key>UserName</key> 
     <string>root</string> 
     <key>GroupName</key>
     <string>wheel</string>
     <key>StandardErrorPath</key> 
     <string>/Users/xxxxx/stderr.log</string> 
     <key>StandardOutPath</key> 
     <string>/Users/xxxxx/stdout.log</string> 
  
     <key>ProgramArguments</key> 
     <array> 
         <string>/usr/local/opt/nginx/bin/nginx</string> 
         <string>-g</string> 
         <string>daemon off;</string> 
     </array> 
     <key>RunAtLoad</key> 
     <true/> 
     <key>WorkingDirectory</key> 
     <string>/usr/local</string> 
     <key>KeepAlive</key> 
     <true/> 
</dict> 
</plist>
```

Comment: Do you have FileVault encryption turned on on this Mac? If so, the "login screen" you see after a reboot isn't a normal login screen, it's a pre-boot authentication screen, and macOS is not actually running yet (it can't, until you give it a password to unlock the encrypted volume). See ["OS X: Launch daemon doesn't start until user logs in"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38828858/os-x-launch-daemon-doesnt-start-until-user-logs-in).

Comment: It sounds reasonable, I will make a try and check.

Answer (score 0):

With this `/Library/LaunchDaemons/machine-test.plist`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>machine-test</string>
        <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
                <string>/bin/bash</string>
                <string>-c</string>
                <string>ps -ef > /tmp/ps.log</string>
        </array>
        <key>RunAtLoad</key>
        <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

when I reboot Ventura, `/tmp/ps.log` contains only system processes, not my (UID 501) processes.

Comment: Don't know what you mean. It is surely only system processes in your log file. My problem is the nginx is not my (UID mine) process, It is a system process, but it does not run.

Comment: I meant your service runs `after` login, my service runs `before` login. Can you run my service to confirm my service runs `before` login on your machine as well ?

Comment: Your result does not effectively mean your services runs after login, only means your service runs before any service under other users instead of root.  The reason now has been clear it is FileVault which forbids launchd running before login as  
Gordon Davisson says above.